# bash parameter expansion- how to replace *all* instances of "pattern" with "string"?

Tags: bash

I've read in [GNU's docs on "Shell Parameter Expansion"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) that, given the following syntax:

```
${parameter//pattern/string}
```

> The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename
> expansion. *Parameter* is expanded and the longest match of *pattern*
> against its value is replaced with *string*... If there are two slashes
> separating *parameter* and *pattern*..., all matches
> of *pattern* are replaced with *string*.

Given the phrase "all matches of *pattern* are replaced with *string*" above, I would expect multiple instances of *pattern* to be replaced with *string* **all at once**, in a single operation, similar to how the `/g` flag works with a global search-and-replace command in a regex.

I have a piece of open-source code (a function named `remove_from_path`) which is implemented as follows:

```
remove_from_path() {
  local path_to_remove="$1"
  local path_before
  local result=":${PATH//\~/$HOME}:"
  local counter=0
  while [ "$path_before" != "$result" ]; do
    counter+=1
    echo "counter: $counter"
    path_before="$result"
    result="${result//:$path_to_remove:/:}"
  done
  result="${result%:}"
  echo "${result#:}"
}
```

The original code did not include the `counter` variable- I added that to check how many iterations the `while` loop would execute.

As we can see, the line `result="${result//:$path_to_remove:/:}"` uses the same double-forward-slash syntax mentioned in the GNU docs.  Given this, I would expect that the `while` loop would only execute once, since all instances of `path_to_remove` should be removed from `result` in one go.

However, that doesn't appear to be the case.  In a `bash` shell (`version 3.2.57`), I update my `$PATH` to be the following:

```
bash-3.2$ PATH="/foo/bar/baz:/foo/bar/baz:/foo/bar/baz:buzz"
```

I then copy/paste the above function into my shell, and run it.  I see the following:

```
bash-3.2$ remove_from_path "/foo/bar/baz"
counter: 01
counter: 011
counter: 0111
buzz
```

Please ignore the fact that the incrementing of the counter didn't work the way I expected, since we can still see 3 executions of the `while` loop.  If the `${parameter//pattern/string}` double-forward-slash syntax really did replace all matches of *pattern* with *string*, why wasn't this accomplished in one iteration of the `while` loop?  Why did we instead need 3 iterations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `${var//pattern/replacement}` operator from ksh93 (also supported by zsh, bash and mksh) only replaces *non-overlapping* occurrences of the pattern.

`${var//xxx/y}` turns `xxxxxx` into `yy`, if it turned it into `yyyy` to replace the 4 overlapping occurrences of `xxx` in there, that would be quite confusing.

Here `$PATH` represents a list of directories (and `~` in that regard is the `~` subdirectory of the current working directory, changing it to `$HOME` is wrong)

Many shells (csh, tcsh, zsh, fish, yash)  map it to one of their array variables.

For instance, in zsh, removing all occurrences of a directory from `$PATH` (mapped to the `$path` array like in `csh`) is just a matter of doing:

```
path=( ${path:#$dir} )
```

(or `path=( "${path[@]:#$dir}" )` to preserve empty elements, but you don't want empty elements in `$PATH`).

`bash` doesn't do that, but you can turn `$PATH` into an array there using the split+glob operator with:

```
set -o noglob
IFS=:
path=( $PATH'' )
```

In bash, like in ksh93 or zsh, `${var//pattern/replacement}` can be applied to all the elements of an array with the `"${array[@]//pattern/replacement}"` syntax, but that won't help as that cannot *remove* elements, just modify them.

So instead, in `bash`, you're left with looping over the elements:

```
remove_from_PATH() {
  local - IFS=: dir to_remove result
  set -o noglob
  for dir in $PATH''; do
    for to_remove do
      if [[ $dir = "$to_remove" ]]; then
        continue 2
      fi
    done
    result+=( "$dir" )
  done
  PATH="${result[*]}"
}
```

(`local -`, copied from the Almquist shell to make changes to the options (like that `set -o` noglob) local to the function needs a relatively recent version of bash, won't work with the ancient 3.2 version you seem to be using).

---

To remove the elements by modifying the `:`-separated list as stored in `$PATH`, you'd need for each `$to_remove`:

- replace a `$to_remove:` found at the start with the empty string.
- replace all `:$to_remove:` in the middle (some possibly overlapping on the `:`s) with `:`
- remove `:$to_remove` at the end with the empty string
- if `$PATH` only contains `$to_remove`, then you're out of option, because an empty `$PATH` means commands are searched in the current directory which is the last thing you want. That should better be handled as an error, or could be just ignored as a pathological case that would not normally happen in real life (like above). Or you can make it `/dev/null` to ensure `$PATH` lookup doesn't find anything.

So:

```
remove_from_PATH() {
  local to_remove dir newpath="$PATH" prev_newpath
  for to_remove do
    while
      prev_newpath=$newpath
      newpath=${newpath#"$to_remove:"}
      newpath=${newpath%":$to_remove"}
      newpath=${newpath//":$to_remove:"/:}
      [[ $newpath != "$prev_newpath" ]]
    do
      continue
    done
  done
  if [[ -n $newpath ]]; then
    PATH=$newpath
  else
    echo >&2 'Refusing to make $PATH empty'
    return 1
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the problem but If I'm wrong please let me now.

In the `$result` variable you have this string:

```
:/foo/bar/baz:/foo/bar/baz:/foo/bar/baz:buzz:
```

And when you apply `result="${result//:$path_to_remove:/:}"` you are replacing all occurrences of `:/foo/bar/baz:` with `:`. But given that pattern the second path is not really matched because of the `:`. For example:

```
:/foo/bar/baz:/foo/bar/baz:/foo/bar/baz:buzz:
```

The bold paths are the occurrences of your pattern.

You can try testing this by using this:

```
result=':/foo/bar/baz1:/foo/bar/baz2:/foo/bar/baz3:buzz:'
echo "${result//:'/foo/bar/baz'?:/:}"
#Output:
:/foo/bar/baz2:buzz:
```

As you can see above the second path (`/for/bar/baz2`) was not affected with the pattern you are using.

So what you can do with the parameter expansion is something like this:

```
echo "${r//'/foo/bar/baz':/}" # The firsy ':' in the pattern was removed
#and instead of replace the pattern with ':' I'm replacing with nothing.
```

So your `remove_from_path` function should look like this:

```bash
remove_from_path() {
  local path_to_remove="$1"
  local path_before
  local result=":${PATH//\~/$HOME}:"
  local counter=0
  while [ "$path_before" != "$result" ]; do
    counter+=1
    echo "counter: $counter"
    path_before="$result"
    result="${result//$path_to_remove:/}"
  done
  result="${result%:}"
  echo "${result#:}"
}
```

However with the logic you have in the function, the loop while will be executed twice. This because the variable `path_before` is set before the `result` variable is set with another value by using the parameter expansion.

Comment: Right, replacement operations like this usually don't look back into the part they already touched, that's also how e.g. `s///` in sed works. Anyway, `${r//:'/foo/bar/baz'/}` would also remove the leading part of `/foo/bar/baz/whatever`.

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks for the clarification and correction! I really was thinking  `${result//:$path_to_remove/}` would have problems with something but I was not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a leading colon too many. Try without:

```
result="/foo/bar/baz:/foo/bar/baz:/foo/bar/baz:buzz"
echo ${result//$path_to_remove:/:}
:::buzz
```

and you see it removed all occurrences in one go, no need for a loop.
Be aware that fiddling with the `PATH` system variable may render your session unusable!

Comment: But since that's `PATH`, leaving those extra colons there is not good: the empty elements will mean the current directory. `${result//$path_to_remove:/}` might be better, though that, too has the issue that e.g. trying to remove `/bar` would also remove the trailing part of `/foo/bar`.